# Drop-in replace Node.js core net server with Vert.x TCP server

Tags: node.js, tcp, vert.x

Say I have a TCP server using Node.js core net library:

```
const wss = net.createServer(s => {
   s.on('data', d => {

   });
});
```

how can I drop in a vert.x tcp server instead of the core Node.js one?
Here are some docs on how to create a tcp server with Vert.x:
https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/js/#_creating_a_tcp_server

But it's entirely unclear which library to install and how to import it.

Should I install?

```
 "vertx3-min": "^3.5.1"
```

or

```
 "vertx3-full": "^3.5.1"
```

the reason I want to use Vert.x instead of Node.js core TCP server is that the former supports the TCP_QUICKACK option.

For more context, see:
https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/21104

Comment: perhaps you can't load vertx with Node.js, only with another runtime?

Comment: That is correct. Vert.x runs on top of the JVM not Node, so the runtime is different.

Comment: Yeah it must use Nashorn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vert.x cannot be used as a drop in replacement as the APIs are different and that was never a goal of the project.

I'd recommend you to check the ES4X project:

https://reactiverse.io/es4x/

As a modern way to bootstrap you Javascript project with vert.x and follow the old blog post:

https://vertx.io/blog/vert-x3-says-hello-to-npm-users/

So you get to know the basics of the API.

Comment: yeah I can only assume then that Vert.x uses Nashorn not Node.js to execute JavaScript